# Functional dependencies in database

Tags: database, database-normalization, relational-algebra, functional-dependencies

I have the following set of functional dependencies on the relation
schema `r(A, B, C, D, E, F )` :

```
A -> BCD
BC -> DE
B -> D
D -> A
```

Can anyone show with explanation how to find the candidate keys for this relation ?

Comment: According to me, I have `(ABCDE) + = ABCDE`, which implies that no subset of ABCDE can form a candidate key and also `(BF ) + = (DF ) + = ABCDEF`. Hence, the candidate keys according to me are `AF`, `BF` and `DF`. AF because its a superkey. Not sure if correct. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Please edit your comment into your question, it does not belong in a comment. Also please give a reference to the process/algorithm you are following & what you've done; otherwise we can't say what you should do or are doing wrong in terms of what you've done. Eg your "hence" is unsound, but you don't explain the (il)logic of how what you did gives your set of CKs. Your current question "how to find the CKs" is too broad--it's asking for section of a textbook, tailored to your example. So pin things down per above to make your question(s) about a very specific situation.

Comment: "I have the following set of FDs" is not enough to answer the question. You need to have a set that you know is a cover. So find out what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: The candidate keys are *(A,F)*, *(B,F)* and *(D,F)*.

Like this [*Wikipedia article*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key#Determining_candidate_keys) says:

> The set of all candidate keys can be computed e.g. from the set of
>   functional dependencies. To this end we need to define the attribute
>   closure α<sup>+</sup> for an attribute set α. The set
>   α<sup>+</sup> contains all attributes that are functionally
>   implied by α.
>
> It is quite simple to find a single candidate key. We **start with a
>   set α** of attributes and try to **remove successively each
>   attribute**. If after removing an attribute the attribute closure
>   stays the same, then this attribute is not necessary and we can
>   **remove it permanently**. We call the result *minimize(α)*. If α is the set of all attributes, then *minimize(α)* is a candidate key.

So now we only need to put this into practice. Let's start with **all attributes** *α<sub>0</sub>=(A,B,C,D,E,F)*. Now we can look whether removing *A* generates a problem. With *α'<sub>0</sub>=(B,C,D,E,F)*, *α'<sub>0</sub><sup>+</sup>* is (B,C,D,E,F,A) (since *D→ A* holds). Now by kicking out *A* permanently and trying to remove *B*, we will end up with **a** candidate key.

1. *α<sub>1</sub>=(B,C,D,E,F)*. Can we throw out *B*? Yes because *α'<sub>1</sub>=(C,D,E,F)* will result in *α'<sub>1</sub><sup>+</sup>=(A,B,C,D,E,F)* (since *D→A* and *A→BCD*).
2. *α<sub>2</sub>=(C,D,E,F)*. Can we throw out *C*? Yes because *α'<sub>2</sub>=(D,E,F)* will result in *α'<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup>=(A,B,C,D,E,F)* (since *D→A* and *A→BCD*).
3. *α<sub>3</sub>=(D,E,F)*. Can we throw out *D*? No because *α'<sub>3</sub>=(E,F)* will result in *α'<sub>3</sub><sup>+</sup>=(E,F)*.
4. *α<sub>3</sub>=(D,E,F)*. Can we throw out *E*? Yes because *α'<sub>3</sub>=(D,F)* will result in *α'<sub>3</sub><sup>+</sup>=(A,B,C,D,E,F)* (since *D→A*; *A→BCD*; and *BC→DE*).
5. *α<sub>4</sub>=(D,F)*. Can we throw out *F*? No because *α'<sub>4</sub>=(D)* will result in *α'<sub>4</sub><sup>+</sup>=(A,B,C,D,E)* (since *D→A*; *A→BCD*; and *BC→DE*).

So now we generated *minimize(α<sub>0</sub>)=α<sub>4</sub>=(D,F)*. We could use a *brute force* approach where in each iteration we iterate over all possible keys we can remove. But this will cost *exponential* time to generate.

The *Wikipedia article* however includes a way to generate **all** candidate keys *polynomial* in the number of keys and the functional dependencies. The algorithm is defined as:

> ```
> function find_candidate_keys(A, F)
> /* A is the set of all attributes and F is the set of functional dependencies */
> K[0] := minimize(A);
> n := 1; /* Number of Keys known so far */
> i := 0; /* Currently processed key */
> while i < n do
>   foreach α → β ∈ F do
>     /* Build a new potential key from the previous known key and the current FD */
>     S := α ∪ (K[i] − β);
>     /* Search whether the new potential key is part of the already known keys */ 
>     found := false;
>     for j := 0 to n-1 do
>       if K[j] ⊆ S then found := true;
>     /* If not, add if 
>     if not found then
>       K[n] := minimize(S);
>       n := n + 1;
>   i := i + 1
> return K
> ```

So if we run the algorithm, we first have to calculate *minimize(A)*, but the nice thing is: we already did that above. So *K[0] = (D,F)*, *n=1* and *i=0*.

Now we take the while loop and start iterating over all functional dependencies.

1. for *A→ BCD*. So now we construct a key *(A,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (which is not the case). Now we minimize it, like: *(A,F)→(A,F)*. So we add a new key *(A,F)*.
2. for *BC→DE*. So now we construct a key *(B,C,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (which is not the case). Now we minimize it, like *(B,C,F)→(B,F)→(B,F)*. So we add *(B,F)*.
3. for *B→D*. So now we construct a key *(B,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
4. for *D→A*. So now we construct a key *(D,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.

This is the end of the first iteration. So *K* is now *K=[(D,F),(A,F),(B,F)]*. *n=3* and now *i=1*. So for *K[i]=(A,F)* we now iterate:

1. for *A→ BCD*. So now we construct a key *(A,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
2. for *BC→DE*. So now we construct a key *(B,C,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
3. for *B→D*. So now we construct a key *(A,B,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
4. for *D→A*. So now we construct a key *(D,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.

This is the end of the second iteration. So *K* is now *K=[(D,F),(A,F),(B,F)]*. *n=3* and now *i=2*. So for *K[i]=(B,F)* we now iterate:

1. for *A→ BCD*. So now we construct a key *(A,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
2. for *BC→DE*. So now we construct a key *(B,C,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
3. for *B→D*. So now we construct a key *(B,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.
4. for *D→A*. So now we construct a key *(B,D,F)*. We check if there is already a subset defined as key (this is the case). We don't add this one.

So at the end *K=[(D,F),(A,F),(B,F)]*. These are all candidate keys.

Comment: @philipxy: but this calculates the closure: since we do this repeatedly. If a new CK is found, we will process it by again performing all FDs on that key, so eventually we search all of these. The point is that we calculate the closure "on-the-fly" so to speak.

Comment: Your comment is unclear, but I see that the paper for the algorithm finds CKs given a cover.